# pointing to array of chars

Tags: array, char

I'm trying to pass a list of files (located in sketch) to be read using a library I write. List can have different filenames and vary in number of files.

How to pass a this array to my library?

for example:

`char *parameterFiles[3] = {"/myIOT_param.json", "/myIOT2_topics.json", "/sketch_param.json"};`

**EDIT_1**

To explain more clearly what are my needs:
Let's say that my library has a class name `myIOT2`. That class holds an array that contains a list of all filenames (what shown here is not all class). Those names are different from one use of the library to the other, and it might not have all 4 files ( can be also 0 files stored ).

I wish to have the flexibilty not to hard code exact filename in advance, but to pass that array as part of my sketch, as show prior to EDIT_1.

```
class myIOT2
{
public:    
const char *parameter_filenames[4] = {nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr}; 


};
```

Comment: You mean a library of your own that you are currently writing?

Comment: @EdgarBonet - Sorry, Yes

Comment: @EdgarBonet please see my comment for  you answer

Comment: I saw the comment. It doesn't seem like something for which you would expect a response.

Comment: @EdgarBonet please explain - adding those variables is critical for the answer. Hope it was explained why.

Comment: Explain what? If you need to add some variables, I see no problem with that. If you have a question, please formulate it as clearly as you can, by editing the question here. Imagine you are talking to someone quite dumb (I am not very good at extrapolating a valid question from very partial information).

Comment: @EdgarBonet please see EDIT_1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass both a pointer to the list, and the length of the list
as an extra argument. The signature of the function may be something
like:

```cpp
void processFiles(const char *fileList[], int fileCount);
```

Note that `const char *fileList[]` is just a fancy way of writing
`const char **fileList`. I find the former more readable, but that is
completely subjective.

Here is a small test code showing this in action:

```cpp
void processFiles(const char *fileList[], int fileCount)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < fileCount; ++i) {
        Serial.print("Processing file ");
        Serial.println(fileList[i]);
    }
}

const char *parameterFiles[3] = {
    "/myIOT_param.json",
    "/myIOT2_topics.json",
    "/sketch_param.json"
};

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    processFiles(parameterFiles, 3);
}

void loop() {}
```

Alternatively, you may put a “sentinel” at the end of the list: a null
pointer that signifies that the list ends there:

```cpp
void processFiles(const char *fileList[])
{
    for (const char **p = fileList; *p; ++p) {
        Serial.print("Processing file ");
        Serial.println(*p);
    }
}

const char *parameterFiles[] = {
    "/myIOT_param.json",
    "/myIOT2_topics.json",
    "/sketch_param.json",
    nullptr
};

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    processFiles(parameterFiles);
}

void loop() {}
```

---

**Edit**: Answering to EDIT_1.

> [My library's] class holds an array that contains a list of all
> filenames

First of all, you have to decide who is responsible for storing those
file names: the library or its client. When you write:

```cpp
const char *parameterFiles[3] = {
    "/myIOT_param.json", "/myIOT2_topics.json", "/sketch_param.json"
};
```

you are creating 4 arrays: an array of 3 pointers named
`parameterFiles`, and three arrays of characters holding the file names.
Note that those 3 arrays are *anonymous*: they are not array
variables. If the client code tries to pass this `parameterFiles` to
your library, the array identifier will decay to a pointer, and your
library will receive that pointer. What should it do with it?

1. The library could just keep a copy of the pointer. The client is then
   responsible for ensuring that it remains valid for as long as the
   library may need it. This practically implies that `parameterFiles`
   should be a global variable, and should not be modified once given to
   the library.
2. The library could make a copy of the array. Then the client is freed
   from this responsibility. However, it is still responsible for
   ensuring that the pointers that were copied from the array remain
   valid, i.e. that the file names stay in the same place in memory.
3. The library could copy the file names themselves. Then the client
   doesn't have any responsibility about keeping pointers valid.

If you choose option 2 or 3, the library will have to hold one or more
arrays. You will then have to choose whether you allocate them
statically, or dynamically with `new`. Dynamic allocation is more
efficient when the arrays can vary greatly in length, but it can raise
issues of memory fragmentation in RAM-constrained devices.

I cannot tell you which option is best: it depends on your use case. In
any case, whatever you choose, you should document it: the user of the
library should know whether they are responsible for keeping any
pointers valid.

In the following, I will assume option 2 with static allocation. This is
consistent with the code snippets in your question. Also, if the client
provides the file names as string literals, then pointers to these
strings remain always valid.

Here is a toy implementation of the `myIOT2` class, where the list of
file names is copied by the constructor into the class:

```cpp
class myIOT2 : public Printable
{
public:
    static const int maxFileCount = 4;

    myIOT2(const char *fileList[], int count) {
        if (count > maxFileCount)
            count = maxFileCount;  // discard extra files
        fileCount = count;
        for (int i = 0; i < fileCount; i++)
            filenames[i] = fileList[i];
    }

    size_t printTo(Print& p) const {
        size_t count = p.print(F("myIOT2["));
        for (int i = 0; i < fileCount; i++) {
            count += p.print('"');
            count += p.print(filenames[i]);
            count += p.print('"');
            if (i < fileCount - 1)
                count += p.print(", ");
        }
        count += p.print(']');
        return count;
    }

private:
    const char *filenames[maxFileCount];
    int fileCount;
};
```

Note that, the array of file names being statically allocated, there is
a hard maximum on the number of files that can be stored. I made the
class `Printable` only for debugging convenience.

And here is an example of this class in use:

```cpp
const int fileCount = 3;

const char *parameterFiles[fileCount] = {
    "/myIOT_param.json", "/myIOT2_topics.json", "/sketch_param.json"
};

myIOT2 iot(parameterFiles, fileCount);

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println(iot);
}

void loop() {}
```

This test sketch prints:

```
myIOT2["/myIOT_param.json", "/myIOT2_topics.json", "/sketch_param.json"]
```

Comment: great idea with "sentinel". Never encountered use of such `for` loop

Comment: To complete my original question - lib will contain `fileList` and `fileCount` to have a pointer for later uses, and Edgar's function can be:

`void processFiles(const char *_fileList[], int _fileCount)
{
  fileCount=_fileCount;
  for (int i = 0; i < fileCount; ++i) {
      Serial.print("Processing file ");
      fileList[i]=_fileList[i];
      Serial.println(fileList[i]);

  }
}`